# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my config:

```
{
   "prefix": ";",
   "token": "xxxxxx",
   "email": "xxxx",
   "password": "xxxx"
}
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
const { rainbow: { email, password } } = require("../../config.json");
```

The error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

How do I fix it?

Comment: Hi WildCoder, what are you looking to do with `rainbow`? Is it a variable you want to declare?

Comment: Sorry took time. Im making a r6 tracker

Comment: I managed to fix it but im getting more errors now. The rainbow thing was preventing me. Sorry im just stupid